# T-SQL return top one field based on count of another

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've struggled to search successfully for this as I haven't figured out a search string describing what I want to do, apologies if this has been covered already.

I have a table that contains among others a contract number, a start date, a serial number and a datestamp. These are Many:Many.

What I'm trying to achieve is to return the start date for each individual contract number with the largest number of unique serial numbers and the most recent datestamp, where that start date is valid.

This, as I guess is obvious to T-SQL experts only returns me the one contract number with the largest number of serials. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
   [Contract ID], [Item Begin Date] AS Start_Date, 
   COUNT([Serial Number]) AS CountSerials, 
   Datestamp
FROM
   SourceTable
GROUP BY 
   [Contract ID], [Item Begin Date], Datestamp
HAVING      
   ([Item Begin Date] > CONVERT(DATETIME, '1900-01-01 00:00:00', 102))
ORDER BY 
   CountSerials DESC, Datestamp DESC
```

Cheers,
Alex

Comment: hint: use a CTE and row_number()

Comment: What version of SQLServer are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can put that into a temporary table (without using TOP (1) or oder by):
I changed some table names in the process,

```
    if exists (select * from tempdb.sys.tables where name = '##tmp')
  drop table ##tmp

  SELECT * into ##tmp
  from 
  (
  select 
   [Contract_ID], [Begin_Date] AS Start_Date, 
   COUNT([serials]) AS CountSerials, 
   Datestamp
FROM
   SourceTable
GROUP BY 
   [Contract_ID], [begin_date], Datestamp
HAVING      
   [begin_date] > CONVERT(DATETIME, '1900-01-01 00:00:00', 102)
   ) a

   select contract_id,Start_Date, max(countserials) as MAXCOUNT, Datestamp  from ##tmp
   group by contract_id,Start_Date,Datestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do a subquery with aggregation and extract your desired results from it:

```
SELECT distinct *
FROM
(
     Select
     [Contract ID], [Item Begin Date] AS Start_Date, 
     COUNT([Serial Number]) OVER(PARTITION BY [Contract ID]) AS CountSerials, 
     datestamp,
     MAX(Datestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY [Contract ID]) maxdatestamp
     FROM
        SourceTable
     WHERE      
        ([Item Begin Date] > CONVERT(DATETIME, '1900-01-01 00:00:00', 102))
) x
WHERE 
datestamp=maxdatestamp
```

Comment: This will return only one row, not one per group